# Use 4-pin S-video cable connector on RGB LED?

Tags: led, power, connector, video, rgb

I'm hoping to make some 4-pin RGB LEDs (R, G, B, GND)  easily hot pluggable, so I'm wondering if 4-pin S-video connectors could be used.

Now, 2 of the pins on a S-video connector are GND, so would it be a good idea to abuse it and connect it to one of the colours? I'm just trying to cause minimal damage if it is plugged to another device with a S video female, and vice versa.

Here's the LED

[image]

Comment: Why would you plug a LED in an S-video? More to the topic, you can't damage an S-video input or output by connecting a LED to in - video signal is too weak to go through the led.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S-Video isn't very common anymore, at least in the 'states. But still, it could happen. Is this for cable-mount, panel-mount, circuit-board mount? How about something like [this](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/SS-104-TT-2/SAM1119-04-ND/1105716)?

[image: 4-position SIP header]
<sub>(source: [digikey.com](http://media.digikey.com/photos/Samtec%20Photos/SS-104-TT-2_sml.jpg))</sub>

- Get two of them for each LED.
- Trim the LED leads flat.
- Insert and very gently solder the LED into socket #1. Keep it cool, plastic will melt.
- Solder socket #2 to your circuit board.
- Connect them together.

Low-profile, easy, fast. It's up to you to make sure it's connected the right way. There are "keyed" variants of these also which make them only connect one-way.

Comment: That's an interesting socket!